# Historical fantasy romance manhua - healed the king of dragons and he takes her in

Tags: story-identification, manga

The female lead was abused by her family and when she was young she healed a dragon who saves her from her situation without realizing it. Her family gave her to the dragon guy in order to spare their lives and he took her from her home because her stepbrother stole something of theirs. She has silver hair and the male lead is dark skinned and he is the king of the dragon race.

Comment: Do you know what sites you read manhuas on?

Answer (score 2):

Is this ***[Neyra's Dragon](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/mtdooke/neyra-s-dragon)***...?

> Neyra Myers of the Celbrid Empire follows her diplomat father to an eastern country, where she meets a magical Dragon Prince, Haeryun, who claims that she is his destined partner.
> Enchanted by this mystical stranger with calm eyes and demeanor, Neyra attempts to escape her troublesome life by following the Dragon Prince to another world where she is made his Queen, but soon discovers she has made a grave mistake. After a Century of unthinkable suffering and emotional torture, she finds a way out, winding time back to a year before their encounter.
>
> Making amends and vowing to never get tangled with Haeryun, Neyra uses her Century of knowledge to pave a different path from her former self.
> However, fate still brings the Dragon Prince to her doorstep, and this time, his once calm eyes are filled with rage and desire.
>
> Will Neyra find a way to escape her destined partner? What is it that the Dragon Prince truly want from her?

The protagonist, Nerya Myers, is the silver-haired daughter of a lord, with whom she has a fractious relationship. When she was young, her biological mother passed away, and she now has a stepmother and a younger half-brother, Graydian, who's referred to as her stepbrother.

One day, Nerya meets a handsome man named Haeryun, whom she feels treats her much more kindly than her own family does. He's actually a dragon prince from another continent, and came to her land specifically to take her as his bride, as he believes they're destined to be together.

After an argument with her father, Nerya runs into Haeryun's arms and asks him to take her away. He subsequently takes her back to his kingdom and marries her, but forces her to cut all ties to her former life among humans, giving her a new name and apparently even going so far as to kill her parents and stepbrother for their "sins."

Nerya was married to Haeryun for a century, but then collapses one day, and wakes up as her younger self, prior to having met him. Knowing of the unhappy marriage that awaits her, she sets about making changes in her life, hoping to steer her future in a better direction.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this ***[Kidnapped Bride](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/ipiodkk/predatory-bride)***...?

> A once in a lifetime opportunity comes to Lucina, the illegitimate daughter of Lord Berek. Hakkan, the great conqueror who rules the dragon lands of Tayer, gives Lucina the opportunity to be his kidnapped bride. Desperate for any kind of freedom, Lucina agrees and steps into the unknown world.

The protagonist, Lucina Berek, is the illegitimate daughter of a lord. She lives in a large, fortified estate with her stepmother and half-brother, and is physically abused by the former.

As a preteen girl, Lucina stumbled upon a wounded dragon lying in a forest. The dragon roared at her, but she showed no fear, and used her magic to heal it.

Ten years later, Lucina is being prepared to be sold as a bride to King Brion, and her naturally silver hair has been dyed blonde.

Her stepbrother reveals that he'd stolen a large quantity of gold from the graves of Tayerites, a race of dragon people from a neighbouring land, with the intention of using it as a dowry for the king. He's scolded for this by his mother, though, who fears the retaliation of the Tayerites.

At that very moment, their estate comes under attack from the Tayerites, led by the Dragon King, Hakan, who's in human form on horseback. He has dark hair and skin.

The stepmother quickly orders that the white flag be raised in surrender, and in exchange for sparing her life and that of her son, she offers to give Hakan her stepdaughter.

When Hakan sees Lucina, he recognises her as the girl who healed his wounds ten years earlier, and decides that their marriage ceremony should be conducted right there on the spot. After that, he returns with her to his own realm.

[image] [image]